# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable" from pandas read_sql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

I am trying to run a SQL command using pyodbc in python.
in which SQL command contains multiple SELECT commands and IF statements.

but I am getting an error as follows

```
columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
conn = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};"
                "SERVER=server_name;"
                "DATABASE=master;"
                "Trusted_Connection=yes;")
cursor = conn.cursor()
script="""

If object_id ('tempdb..#Temp1')is not null
drop table #Temp1
Select distinct  a1.some_ID into #Temp1
from DOC.dbo.Document_tbl (NOLOCK)a1
from #Temp1 a1
If object_id ('tempdb..#Temp2')is not null
Drop table #Temp2
select distinct v2.some_data
into #Temp2 from tbl_name (nolock) v2 

If object_id ('tempdb..#Results')is not null
drop table #Results
select distinct a1.*,b1.####
into #Results
from #Temp1 a1
left join #Temp2 b1 on a1.## = b1.##
Select * from #Results
"""

df = pd.read_sql(script, cnxn)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('result.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name ='bar')
writer.save()
```

Comment: The error says that there is nothing in the cursor, basically, it means that your returned nothing.

Comment: Please remove those `NOLOCK` query hints unless you understand exactly why you need them and the risks of using them, including retrieving invalid data and data that does not exist

Comment: Thank you Gord Thompson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL command text that contains multiple SQL statements is called an *anonymous code block*. An anonymous code block can return multiple results, where each result can be

- a row count,
- a result set containing zero or more rows of data, or
- an error.

The following example fails ...

```python
sql = """\
SELECT 1 AS foo INTO #tmp;
SELECT * FROM #tmp;
"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn)
# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

... because the first `SELECT ... INTO` returns a row count before the second `SELECT` returns its result set.

The fix is to start the anonymous code block with `SET NOCOUNT ON;` which suppresses the row count and only returns the result set:

```python
sql = """\
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT 1 AS foo INTO #tmp;
SELECT * FROM #tmp;
"""
df = pd.read_sql_query(sql, cnxn)
# no error
```

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else who is still getting this error, I have found that for some statements (A window function that aggregated null values) I also need to include `SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;`.